# pandas add enumeration column based on category

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

df_all:

```
Keyword    Type        Position
test       Video         1
test       News          2
test       News          3
test       Image         4
test       Image         5
test       Image         6
test       Video         7
test       News          8
test2      Video         1
test2      News          2
test2      Image         3
test2      News          4
test2      Video         5
test2      News          6
```

Now I would like to create seperate dataframes for each type, create a new column  and "reindex" the position for each keyword so that the end result looks like so:

df_news:

```
Keyword    Type        Position    Position_New
test       News          2               1
test       News          3               2
test       News          8               3
test2      News          2               1 
test2      News          4               2
test2      News          6               3
```

df_video:

```
Keyword    Type        Position    Position_New
test       Video         1                1
test       Video         7                2 
test2      Video         1                1
test2      Video         5                2
```

Can I achieve this with some groupby magic?

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: for the `Position_New`: `df.groupby(['Keyword','Type']).cumcount().add(1)`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much. Would you mind posting the answer so that I can credit you for solving my question?

Comment: @QuangHoang could you post your answer, please? Thanks in advance.